# What is the shortest way to check for several elements in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I have this list:
`list = ["Coin", "Stick", "Coin"]`
I want to check if the list contains n amount of coins. What is the simplest method of doing this, without changing the original list?

I have tried `if ["Coin", "Coin"] in list` but that only works if the coins are next to each other.

Comment: You mean `list.count`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `count` method:

```
items = ["Coin", "Stick", "Coin"]
print(2 == items.count("Coin"))
```